# How do I make someone an op via a remote client such as PuTTY?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to manage my Minecraft Server via PuTTY, but how would I make someone an OP using the command line?

What is the step-by-step method using PuTTY to make someone an OP on a Minecraft Server?

Comment: Huh?  Do you have a remote server that you need to admin?

Comment: And if so, what OS is the server running?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server management not directly related to gaming

Comment: @kalina - I've reworded it to focus more on the 'adding an op' side then - as opposed to the generic "using PuTTY to manage Minecraft"

Comment: Unless Minecraft has special remote methods of connection, all the user needs is a method of connecting to that server.  That's a question for SU, not us.

Answer (score 4):

In order to use PuTTY to manage a Minecraft server you will need the following;

- [A copy of PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/)
- A Minecraft server running on a PC or hosted server with an SSH server running on it
- The user credentials the Minecraft server is running under

## Connecting to a server

Once you've got the above. Start PuTTY up and connect to the server by entering the server hostname or IP address into the Host Name (or IP address) box:

[image]

Enter the username and password, note that the password won't show anything when you type:

[image]

You're now connected to your server.

## Adding an op by editing ops.txt

Change to the folder that your Minecraft server is running from if you've logged in with the account running Minecraft, or switch user to the account that is.

Edit the ops.txt file using whichever editor you have available (for example, `vi`, `emacs`, `nano`, etc) and add the player to the file.

Save the file and restart the Minecraft server.